# API and Rails with JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, api

I'm really confused on the concept of this. 
I'm supposed to make `API` that handles `JSON` responses. I read [this](http://blog.gomiso.com/2011/06/27/building-a-platform-api-on-rails/) 
and other places, they all showed example on how to do it for the `show` or `index` aspect of the controller. I understand that, where you outputs all the attributes of the model. But my main question is, if somebody were to create or edit, what do I do with the whole `JSON` on there?

Answer (score 1):

If all you need to do is pass back a 200 for a successfull create, then don't creating a response.

render :nothing => true

If on the other hand, you added some important information to the object that you are updating that the client will require (If you are not sure, then assume that the client will require it), then you should pass the updated object's attributes back

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.json {render :json => {... }}
end
```

Comment: I don't know what pass back a 200 means?

Comment: Passing back a 2xx html code means that the http request was succesfull.  Most ajax clients (Jquery included) will interpret an http code of 2xx as successfull and trigger your success() callback.